# Wordpress filter CPT archive by parent (url match)

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have 2 custom post types

**Offices**

```
    register_post_type('offices',
        [
            'labels' => [
                'name' => __( 'Offices' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Office' )
            ],
            'description' => 'Our Office.',
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive' => false,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-building',
            'support' => ['title', 'custom_fields', 'page-attributes']
        ]
    );
```

**Office members**

```
   //Team Members
    register_post_type( 'office_members',
        [
            'labels' => [
                'name' => __( 'Team Members' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Team Member' )
            ],
            'description' => 'Team members for offices.',
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'has_archive' => 'offices/([^/]+)/members',
            'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=offices',
            'support' => ['title', 'custom_fields', 'page-attributes']
        ]
    );
```

I want the following urls to work

`example.com/offices` - Shows the office archive page

`example.com/offices/([^/]+)` - Show the single office page

`example.com/offices/([^/]+)/members` - Show the members archive page where parent is the office

`example.com/offices/([^/]+)/members/([^/]+)` - Show the single member page

I have the following rewrite rules for the office members

```
    add_permastruct('office_members', '/offices/%office%/members/%office_members%', false,  ['walk_dirs' => false]);
    add_rewrite_tag('%office_members%', '([^/]+)', 'office_members=');
    add_rewrite_rule('^offices/([^/]+)/members/([^/]+)?','index.php?office_members=$matches[2]','top');
```

All of my urls work except for the members archive page. It loads the template file `archive-office_members.php` which is great, but it doesn't detect the parent office in the url. So instead of it only showing members for that office it just shows all members.

How can I set my url so that it shows the members archive page, but only shows members based on the `office` in the url, and so all 4 of my urls work?